# How do you create a complex variable in java?

Tags: variables, constructor, numbers

I'm using eclipse and messing around with complex numbers. I am not sure how to do this. I know how to do an integer and a double but not the complex type. I found something that said to do

```
Complex c= new Complex(1.0.3.0); // 1+3i
```

but that doesnt quite work out. It just gives an error that says the constructor is undefined?

Comment: That's from Apache Commons. Do you have that installed?

Comment: I think what you need is new Complex(1,3);

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `Complex.class` file in the same folder as your other code?
I grabbed a `Complex` class from [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java), created the `Complex.class` file with `javac Complex.java` and then running the following code (filenames `example.java` and `example.class`) was not a problem:

```
class example {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Complex a = new Complex(1,2);
    }
}
```

Comment: these may be silly questions but when i go to the link you posted, do i just copy the whole thing? and what do i save it as? Then in order to have the user input the real and imaginary parts, what would the code look like?

Comment: You just download the file as-is (it is a .java file) and save it to the same directory where you have the code trying to create a complex number. You need to compile the Complex.java file to a Complex.class file with "javac Complex.java" from the command line. After that, you should be able to create Complex-objects. The first number when constructing the object is the real part (I used 1) and the second number is the imaginary part (I used 2). In order to have a user specify the arguments to the constructor you simply ask for two numbers.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to handle user input, the link did not fit into the first comment. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html

Comment: i understand user inputs (numberDecimal|numberSigned) but im not sure how the code would be. Would it look like Complax a=new Complex(input1,input2); where input1 and input2 are the text field that the user fills? what do you mean by compile from the command line? is that in eclipse or are you talking about terminal (im on linux)

Comment: You simply ask the user for two numbers and store them in variables, let's call them num1 and num2. Then you can create Complex c = new Complex(num1, num2). How to get user input and store it is explained in the link I posted above. I don't use eclipse, are you asking how to create a .class file from a .java file? If yes, that's a quick google for you on how to do it in eclipse if you don't want to use the linux command line.

Comment: i did that and got the complex class to show up in the folder but there is an error in the java file on the first line. The "/" and "javac" have errors.